# IS vs ARE question

Tags: grammar

Help me with the correct sentence.

There ***IS*** only three wine glasses left.

or

There ***ARE*** only three wine glasses left.

Comment: This is off-topic for multiple reasons: Asking for rephrasing, asking about whether something is grammatically correct, and asking for proofreading are all firmly off-topic here. Have closed this question, but you might consider browsing the English site. I imagine this may have already been addressed there, and you may get an answer that explains the grammatical issues more thoroughly than we can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To figure out whether to use **IS** or **ARE** look at the noun.  Since there are *three* wine glasses you would use **ARE**.  If the sentence was about one wine glass it would read: "There **is** only one wine glass left."

Comment: So when you discuss more than one of something, ARE is correct? Singular would be IS?

Comment: IS should be used when the subject is singular.  There are a couple of examples of this in http://english.stackexchange.com/ if you look.

Comment: @Firemarble Yes, you are completely correct. IS is the form of the verb used for singular nouns. ARE is the form used for plural.